# How can I make a digital variable not accept the text variable

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, if-statement, int

```
back:      Console.Write("The first number=   ");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (x== string ) { goto back;} // here my proplem
```

How can I model this: Meaning if x input string `goto` back

Comment: Goto is sometimes useful, even necessary. But not here!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a **loop** with **int.TryParse** that checks if the value is number and **break** from the loop when the Number is entered correctly.

```
    int x;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Write("The first number=   ");

        bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);

        if (success)
            break;
    }
```

Or if you wish to use `goto`

```
int x;

back:
Console.Write("The first number=   ");

bool success = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);

if (!success)
    goto back;
```